# SSHD accepts connection but closes after method 'none'

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd, glibc, buildroot

I'm trying to ssh to my local sshd, but the connection is detected by sshd it closes before I get a password prompt.

The server is running buildroot and uses glibc.

I've compared the logs with working ssh/sshd logs, but the only difference I can find is the sudden exit after the method 'none', which does not give me any leads.

I've tried poking around in the file system to check for missing files or invalid file properties. I've also tried invoking it directly instead of running it as a systemd service.

sshd output:

```
Started OpenSSH server daemon.
debug2: load_server_config: filename /etc/ssh/sshd_config
debug2: load_server_config: done config len = 336
debug2: parse_server_config_depth: config /etc/ssh/sshd_config len 336
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:18 setting HostKey /static/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:19 setting HostKey /static/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:20 setting HostKey /static/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:32 setting PermitRootLogin yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:41 setting AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:108 setting Subsystem sftp        /usr/libexec/sftp-server
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_8.6, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:FLrw6X2h9xj+aa2GQduIb1QCAzbI1ooWNyD86gA2iV8
debug1: private host key #1: ssh-dss SHA256:q6emWCLwbPVmiHfiAjLhgximILI+jvmNjxmvIHT3upQ
debug1: private host key #2: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:efea0vwUrNps9M0NMoj4G7XpnGWHXnnEHlSWqbg9fX0
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-D'
debug1: rexec_argv[2]='-e'
debug1: rexec_argv[3]='-ddd'
debug3: already daemonized
debug3: oom_adjust_setup
debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 4 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 22.
debug3: fd 5 is not O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 8 config len 336
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
debug3: send_rexec_state: done
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug3: recv_rexec_state: entering fd = 5
debug3: ssh_msg_recv entering
debug3: recv_rexec_state: done
debug2: parse_server_config_depth: config rexec len 336
debug3: rexec:18 setting HostKey /static/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
debug3: rexec:19 setting HostKey /static/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
debug3: rexec:20 setting HostKey /static/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
debug3: rexec:32 setting PermitRootLogin yes
debug3: rexec:41 setting AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
debug3: rexec:108 setting Subsystem sftp        /usr/libexec/sftp-server
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_8.6, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:FLrw6X2h9xj+aa2GQduIb1QCAzbI1ooWNyD86gA2iV8
debug1: private host key #1: ssh-dss SHA256:q6emWCLwbPVmiHfiAjLhgximILI+jvmNjxmvIHT3upQ
debug1: private host key #2: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:efea0vwUrNps9M0NMoj4G7XpnGWHXnnEHlSWqbg9fX0
debug3: already daemonized
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from 127.0.0.1 port 47472 on 127.0.0.1 port 22
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.6
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: ssh_sandbox_init: preparing seccomp filter sandbox
debug2: Network child is on pid 17115
debug3: preauth child monitor started
debug3: privsep user:group 1001:1001 [preauth]
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 1001/1001 [preauth]
debug3: ssh_sandbox_child: setting PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS [preauth]
debug3: ssh_sandbox_child: attaching seccomp filter program [preauth]
debug3: append_hostkey_type: ssh-dss key not permitted by HostkeyAlgorithms [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 20 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 20 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug2: local server KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha>
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 [preauth]
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64>
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64>
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
debug2: peer client KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha>
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.c>
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64>
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64>
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 30 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT received [preauth]
debug3: mm_sshkey_sign: entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send: entering, type 6 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive: entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 6
debug3: mm_answer_sign: entering
debug3: mm_answer_sign: KEX signature 0x4f8e80(101)
debug3: mm_request_send: entering, type 7
debug2: monitor_read: 6 used once, disabling now
debug3: mm_sshkey_sign: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_SIGN [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect: entering, type 7 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive: entering [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 31 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 21 [preauth]
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1 [preauth]
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: Sending SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 7 [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 21 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0 [preauth]
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 5 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 6 [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug3: mm_getpwnamallow: entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send: entering, type 8 [preauth]
debug3: mm_getpwnamallow: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect: entering, type 9 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive: entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive: entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 8
debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow: entering
debug2: parse_server_config_depth: config reprocess config len 336
debug3: auth_shadow_acctexpired: today 18864 sp_expire -1 days left -18865
debug3: account expiration disabled
debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow: sending MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM: 1
debug3: mm_request_send: entering, type 9
debug2: monitor_read: 8 used once, disabling now
debug2: input_userauth_request: setting up authctxt for root [preauth]
debug3: mm_inform_authserv: entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send: entering, type 4 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method none [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive: entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 4
debug3: mm_answer_authserv: service=ssh-connection, style=
debug2: monitor_read: 4 used once, disabling now
debug3: user_specific_delay: user specific delay 0.000ms [preauth]
debug3: ensure_minimum_time_since: elapsed 28.499ms, delaying 26.813ms (requested 6.914ms) [preauth]
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug3: mm_request_receive: entering
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: Killing privsep child 17115
```

The /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.103 2018/04/09 20:41:22 tj Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

HostKey /static/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /static/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /static/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
#UsePAM no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this buildroot issue](https://bugs.busybox.net/show_bug.cgi?id=13671) the call to `clock_nanosleep_time64` or `clock_gettime64` is problematic and causes:

> The OpenSSH server on my device closes the connection abruptly

I'm able to login after adding [this patch](https://bugs.busybox.net/show_bug.cgi?id=13671#c6) to the openssh source code before building.

Answer (score 0):

Change `UsePAM no` to `UsePAM yes` and restart sshd

```
service sshd restart
```

Comment: The issue persists unfortunately..